# how to grep complex hierarcy?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, solaris

I have a file as:-

```
start apple
1 a
2 b
3 c
start orange
4 a
5 b
start mango
1 a
start a/b/c
5 z
end
4 b
end
6 c
end
start banana
3 c
end
4 d
5 e
end
```

I want the output as :-

```
1 apple/a
2 apple/b
3 apple/c
4 apple/orange/a
5 apple/orange/b
1 apple/orange/mango/a
5 apple/orange/mango/a/b/c/z
4 apple/orange/mango/b
6 apple/orange/c
3 apple/banana/c
4 apple/d
5 apple/e
```

I just want to grep the hierarchy of the numbers with fastest possible method

Comment: What do you mean with 'fastest possible method'? CPU performance, simplicity, ...?

Comment: I just want to say that any method using either sed or awk or anything else or combination of all these so that the run time will be minimum possible.
In my original file there are 3700000 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical `awk` job:

```
awk '$1 == "start" {d[++n] = $2; next}
     $1 == "end" {n--; next}
     {
       printf "%s ", $1
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s/",d[i]
       print $2
     }'
```

(on Solaris, you might need `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk`).

Though it could also be done with `sed`:

```
sed '/^start /{s///;x;G;s/\n//;s:$:|:;h;d;}
     /^end/{g;s:[^|]*|$::;h;d;}
     G;s/ \(.*\)\n\(.*\)/ \2\1/;y:|:/:'
```

(here assuming the paths don't contain `|` characters).

Comment: Thank you very much Stephane :)
It works for me , but I need to check it on my original file as it contain around 3700000 lines , I just worried about the run time for that file.

Comment: Hi Stephane,
there is a corner case if the name have "/" in it. then the output is not right , i mean to say that if there are mango/fig instead of only mango then the output is not correct.
Please consider this also.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in python.

The script reads from `stdin` and prints to stdout.
It also expects the input to match a certain format. If you've got lines that don't match that format, you'd have to adjust the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput

hierarchy = []

for line in fileinput.input():
    parts = line.rstrip().split(' ')
    if parts[0] == 'start':
        hierarchy.append(parts[1])
    elif parts[0] == 'end':
        hierarchy.pop()
    else:
        print parts[0] + ' ' + '/'.join(hierarchy)+'/'+ parts[1]
```